# No conditional formatting on page 2 in the subreport

Tags: ms-access, conditional-formatting, ms-access-2016, subreport

I have a Report with a subreport. The subreport has several conditional formatting fields with several conditional formattings for each field.
On page one the formatting is fine. But on Page two it lost some of the formatting conditions.

[image: This is page one]

The dark red fields are normally unvisible. They are containing the Rownumber. This field is used for formatting the month cols if they are without value.

[image: page 2 without the highlighted line]

It seems that this condition would not work on page 2!

(  Condition example for odd-rows: [amount_month_2]=0 AND ([RowNum] Mod 2)<>0  )

Any suggestion?

For more detail I set borders to some fields, so you will see that the fields are hiding the background of the row.

[image]

Comment: Is second image for page 2? What is wrong with it - it still shows red format just as page 1. Is lack of grey on alternate rows the issue?

Comment: I cannot replicate issue.

Comment: Yes, the lack of grey on the alternate rows is the issue. The conditions for that are at the same place as the conditions for red, green and yellow formats.

Comment: Why would you need CF for alternate row color? AlternateBackColor is a property of Group and Detail sections. I did not set a CF for alternate row and I get grey alternate rows on each page.

Comment: I need this because the backstyle for the fields of month_amount is normal and not transparent, so they are hiding the normal AltenateBackColor (see it on page two. left and right you see the AlternateBackColor). And for CF I have no option to switch the BackStyle to transparent (or I haven't found it yet).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that. As I said, I did not use CF for alternate color, just let AlternateBackColor property apply. Perhaps you need to provide the CF rules for red, green, yellow.

Comment: For better understanding I edit the thread with a new screen.

Comment: Sorry, that additional image doesn't really help. I already understood issue and still cannot replicate in my report. AlternateBackColor property works, regardless of CF. Since I cannot replicate, I cannot offer solution.